# JDBC Error : java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08002: sequence is not yet defined in this session

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Below is my sequence  that i created :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  SEQ_SURVEY INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOCACHE  NOCYCLE ;
```

in my JDBC Code, I am using :

```
String currentValueFromSequence = "SELECT SEQ_SURVEY.CURRVAL FROM DUAL";
PreparedStatement getCurrValFromSeq = con.prepareStatement(currentValueFromSequence);

ResultSet getSurveyResponseID = getCurrValFromSeq.executeQuery();
```

Its throwing an error stating that :

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08002: sequence SEQ_SURVEY.CURRVAL is not yet defined in this session
```

I am not able to understand why this code is not running in my QA Environment whereas this code ran perfectly fine in my Dev Environment.

Can any expert provide their suggestion ?

Comment: How did you create the sequence from your JDBC code?

Comment: I’d guess your connection pool is defined differently in the two environments, and/or you’re utilising them differently - more concurrnt users meaning you’re using more distinct DB sessions in QA, so nextval and currval are happening if different sessions in QA but not in dev?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : I created the sequence separately from Oracle SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call NEXVAL first. That's why you are getting the error.

SELECT SEQ_SURVEY.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL

The Oracle NEXTVAL function is used to retrieve the next value in a sequence. The Oracle NEXTVAL function **MUST BE** called before calling the CURRVAL function, or an error will be thrown. The Oracle CURRVAL function is used to access the current value of the specified sequence. Note that CURRVAL can only be used if NEXTVAL has been referenced in the **current user session** at least once.